# Nextjs Nested Dynamic Routes (catch all?)

Tags: routes, next.js, dynamic

I have searched many articles and posts regarding this topic, but they don't seem to make a lot of sense to me. I am new to Nextjs and dynamic routes in general, so I'm hoping someone can explain this clearly to me for my situation.

My page structure looks something like below. And what I want to do is combine the paths into one.
So I would have something like this:

```
-Page
--Category
---[slug].js
--Post
---[slug].js
```

I understand how this structure works. I would end up with two different routes, one that would be domain/category/[slug], and one that would be domain/post/[slug].

This is not what I want. I want it to be domain/category/[slug]/post/[slug].

I have also tried nesting the folder structure like below, though I'm not sure if that would work, or if I'm just not doing is correctly. Not to mention many variations and structures. I'm tired of beating my head against the wall.

```
-Page
--Category
---index.js
---[slug].js
---Post
----[slug].js
```

I'm fairly certain that the answer lies with using a catch all like [...params], I'm just not sure of the correct way to do, that makes sense to me.

An example of the code I'm using can be found here:https://github.com/adrianhajdin/project_graphql_blog/tree/main/pages

My structure is exactly the same, just folder and names may be different.

**Edit:** I should also note, I have no issue with changing the current site folder structure to accomplish this. I just don't want to change my CMS structure I currently have set up.

**Edit 2:** Based on feedback from @maxeth my page/[category]/index.js page looks like this minus the HTML:

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const posts = await getCategoryPost(params.category);

  return {
    props: { posts },
    revalidate: 60 * 20,
  };
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const categories = await getCategories();

  return {
    paths: categories.map((el) => ({ params: { category: el } })),
    fallback: false,
  };
}
```

Although I'm not sure if getStaticProps/`const posts = await getCategoryPost(params.category)` is correct. Should it be `(params.category)`?

It should also be noted that getCategoryPost and getCategories queries are being imported if that wasn't obvious already. I'm sure it is though. They can be found here:

> https://github.com/adrianhajdin/project_graphql_blog/blob/main/services/index.js

I'm not sure if the slug in the CMS also needs to be renamed to reflect the `[category]` directory. Currently, it's just named Slug.

**Edit 3:** The path up through `pages/category/[category]` works fine. It's when I get to `pages/category/[category]/post/[slug]` that I get a **404**.

Post/[slug] getstaticprops and getstaticpaths looks like the following:

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const data = await getPostDetails(`${params.category}/${params.slug}`);
  return {
    props: {
      post: data,
    },
  };
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const posts = await getPosts();
  return {
    paths: posts.map(({ node: { slug } }) => ({
      params: { category: slug.category, slug: slug.slug },
    })),
    fallback: true,
  };
}
```

The Post queries look like this:

```
export const getPosts = async () => {
  const query = gql`
    query MyQuery {
      postsConnection(orderBy: createdAt_DESC) {
        edges {
          cursor
          node {
            content {
              html
              raw
              text
            }
            author {
              bio
              name
              id
              photo {
                url
              }
            }
            createdAt
            slug
            title
            excerpt
            featuredImage {
              url
            }
            categories {
              name
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `;

  const result = await request(graphqlAPI, query);

  return result.postsConnection.edges;
};

export const getPostDetails = async (slug) => {
  const query = gql`
    query GetPostDetails($slug: String!) {
      post(where: { slug: $slug }) {
        content {
          html
          text
          raw
        }
        title
        excerpt
        featuredImage {
          url
        }
        author {
          name
          bio
          photo {
            url
          }
        }
        createdAt
        slug
        content {
          html
          raw
          text
        }
        categories {
          name
          slug
        }
      }
    }
  `;

  const result = await request(graphqlAPI, query, { slug });

  return result.post;
};
```

What the heck am I missing? It has to be something really simple. I'm just not smart enough to see it.

**Edit 4:** The **404** was caused by a casing mistake. Where I was typing /post/[slug].js instead of /Post/, since my directory was named Post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with the following structure:

```
└── pages
    └── category 
        ├── index.js // this is the "overview page" of all categories
        └── [category] 
            └── index.js // this is the "overview page" of a specific category
                └── post
                    └── [slug].js // this is an actual article page for that specific category
```

Note that you cannot use the dynamic-route name `[slug]` twice inside the folder `category`, because we will have to return objects with the path names as keys, e.g. [category] -> {category: ...}, [slug] -> {slug: ...}, so they have to be unique for next to tell for which folder you are returning the slugs inside `getStaticPaths`.

Now if you use `getStaticPaths`, you need to return the specific slug for the page, as well as the "slugs" of the potential parent page inside `params: {...}` in order for the pages to be pre-generated.

So inside `category/[category]/index.js`, you would need to do something like this:

```js
export async function getStaticPaths(context){
 // [...] fetch all categories from CMS

 const allCategories = await getAllCategoriesFromCMS(); 
 // allCategories includes all of the categories from your CMS:
 // e.g. ["category-A", "category-B", "category-C", ...] 

return {
  paths: allCategories.map(el => ({ params: { category: el } }))
};
}
```

Which is then accessible within `getStaticProps` like this:

```js
export async function getStaticProps({params}){
 console.log(params.category) // can be any of the dynamic categories you fetched and returned inside getStaticPaths
}
```

...

And the same concept applies to `category/[category]/post/[slug].js`, just that you now have to return/handle 2 "slugs" `[category]` and `[slug]` inside `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps`:

```js
export async function getStaticPaths(context){
 // [...] fetch all posts and the specific categories they belong to from CMS

 const allPosts = await getAllPostsFromCMS(); 
 // allPosts includes all of the posts/articles from your CMS, assuming the posts have a relationship with their respective category:
 /* e.g. [ 
{category: "category-A", postSlug:"some-article-for-category-A", author: "some author", articleContent: "..."}, 
{category: "category-B", postSlug:"some-article-for-category-B", author: "some author", articleContent: "..."}, 
] 
*/

return {
  paths: [ // once again, we need to call the keys 'category' and 'slug' because we called the dynamic routes '[category]' and '[slug].js'
   allPosts.map(el => ({ params: { category: el.category, slug: el.postSlug } }))
  ],
};
}
```

and in `getStaticProps`:

```js
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  console.log(params);
  // You are guaranteed to have matching categories and slugs in here, for example
  //     {category: category-A, slug:some-article-for-category-A}
  // or  {category: category-B, slug:some-article-for-category-B}

  // You can use these params to fetch the article entry from the CMS
  const article = await fetchFromCMS(`${params.category}/${params.slug}`);

  // [...]
}
```

Now, for example, one of the articles will be accessible under `localhost:3000/category/category-A/post/some-post-for-category-A`

Comment: I understand the structure of the layout, but I don't seem to understand the staticpaths. Or at least, it doesn't seem like what I want to achieve. Again, please excuse my ignorance if I'm not understanding something correctly, but what it seems to me is that you are suggesting I add each individual category, and post in param on their respective index pages. Is that correct, or am I missing something? If is that is the case, then that doesn't seem to be reasonable, as I have no idea how many categories or posts I will have.

Comment: @NotReallySure No, for example inside ```getStaticPaths``` of ```category/[category]/index.js``` you have to fetch all possible categories from your CMS, and based on the results you get, you return the array of slugs dynamically (I have hard-coded it just for demo-purposes because I don't know anything about your CMS) to pre-build your category overview page. The same thing happens for ```category/[category]/post/[slug].js```, but here, you have to fetch both categories and article-slugs and return them dynamically instead of the hard-coded way I did for demo-purposes again.

Comment: @NotReallySure I've reworked the examples. Hope it makes a bit more sense now :)

Comment: Just to be clear because I think you got this part wrong based on your comment: When I mention something like ```category/[category]/index.js```, I actually mean a directory called ```[category]``` (that's how Next.js dynamic routes work), and I don't mean creating separate directories for each category

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't implying that I make directory for each category. I was referring to your original hardcoded params examples. I didn't know it was just for demo. Anyway, I think for the most part the original code does more or less the same as what you describe. I think the problem I run into is with the nesting and changing the original category/[slug] to category/[category]. I keep running into an error: `Error: A required parameter (category) was not provided as a string in getStaticPaths for /news/[category]`. I'm thinking it has to do with the queries which I'm importing.

Comment: If you look at the getCategories, and getCategoryPost here: [link](https://github.com/adrianhajdin/project_graphql_blog/blob/main/services/index.js) that may help to sort it out. Currently, the slug is just named slug in the CMS. Do I need to change it there as well?

Comment: One last thing I think will show where I'm at. Getstaticprops looks like this:             
 `export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const posts = await getCategoryPost(params.category);

  return {
    props: { posts },
    revalidate: 60 * 20,
  };
}`          And getStaticPaths looks like this:                                                                 
 `export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const newsCategories = await getNewsCategories();

  return {
    paths: newsCategories.map((el) => ({ params: { category: el } })),
    fallback: false,
  };
}`

Comment: If getNewsCategories() returns an array of strings it looks good to me. So probably the getStaticPaths of the article page (…/post/[slug].js) is the issue

Comment: If you look at my 3rd and final edit on this, you will see where I'm stuck. It is the .../post/[slug].js where I'm stuck, getting a 404 page. I don't even get an error. At least that would be something. It has to be something simple. Everything is set up as suggested as far as I can tell. I give up if I can't get it after this. I appreciate all the time and hep you have given me so far.

Comment: @NotReallySure If you get a 404 page, the origin of the error must be ```getStaticPaths``` or bad file-naming. Did you name the file ```[slug]``` or ```[slug].js``` ?  It has to be the latter, but in your edit you forgot the ```.js```. If that's not the issue, you could try logging the ```posts.map(...)``` part to see what it exactly is that you're returning. If that doesn't help, I'd suggest creating a new question because this issue is outside the scope of the original file-structure problem. All I can tell is that the setup I posted works, as I use it myself for the exact same use case too.

Comment: I just noticed one thing in your GraphQL query: It seems like a post can have more than just 1 category because you query ```[...] categories { name slug } [...]```, or is it just 1?.  Also, inside ```getStaticPaths``` of ```post/[slug].js``` you are destructuring the slug with: ```{ node: { slug } }```, but isn't ```slug``` just a plain (string) value? Shouldn't you do something like ```paths: posts.map(({ node: { slug, categories } }) => ({ params: { category: categories.slug, slug: slug }, })),``` assuming ```categories``` is a single object like ```{slug: "", name:""}```?

Comment: It would be useful if you did a ```console.log()``` of what the ```getPosts()``` query returns.

Comment: I just gave up. I just don't want to spend any more time on this. Yes, it was [slug].js too. The queries are the way the original project was created. I did not create them. I will just need to visit this another time. I appreciate your help on this. I'm certain your answer is correct, so I marked it so.

Comment: One last thing to note. The 404 message was caused by a stupid oversight by me. My directory was named 'Post' and I was testing by going to domain/category/[category]/post/[slug]. It was a casing mistake. Now, I think all I need to do is adjust my query and I think I should be good. Of course, that is a different topic as you said. Thanks again for the help.